# How can I document or track bouldering activity?

Tags: tracking, bouldering

I have recently taken up bouldering. In my city, there is a gym dedicated to bouldering with lots of indoor climbing space and routes.

I also like to track my progress and workout activities.  Most of the other activities I've tried are simple to track (i.e., for running I can easily track distance and time).

However, I'm at a loss as to how to track bouldering activity. Things I have tried:

- **Apps**: I searched the Android store and Google for bouldering apps and tried out 5 of them. The most common problem is that they asked for an individual gym and mine wasn't listed (and they didn't have a feature for me to add one).
- **Physical Logs**: I searched Amazon for physical (print) bouldering journals. These exist, but seem to be tailored to climbing outdoors. Many of them had features to track general locations ("Slag Quarry, NE face").

Answer (score 1):

I'm afraid I don't have a definitive answer, but I'm like you in finding that it helps to document in *some* way.

I suspect you'll never find a perfect solution, because of its nature. If I go cycling - I press start, ride the bike, press stop, upload to Strava. Jobs a good 'un.

But with bouldering you've got so many other variable to consider. I find I want to log successes, failures, projects, grades - and then every few weeks the gym changes all the problems anyway.

And then of course there's the problem that the grade ratings per route/gym/setter are kind of subjective and not entirely accurate anyway.

So what I do is keep a fairly simple log of success versus fails at routes, per marked grade. In a spreadsheet. That way I can track my progress (what little there is!) through the grades and demonstrate that I am improving.

I get home from a session, then think through (I'm not too worried about *total* accuracy) and try to remember roughly how many routes at each grade I climbed, and roughly what percentage of each of those I was successful at. That way I can track that I'm broadly improving at any given grade.

That's about it really.

One of my local gyms has recently starting using one of those apps you mentioned, and being a Strava user I was keen to give it a go - but I find it really clunky to use and quickly gave up.

Answer (score 1):

I'd recommend the [Rock Climber's Training Manual](https://amzn.to/2U4SA2q), and conveniently enough they have a [training log](https://amzn.to/2UM3DLd) that goes along with it.

Whether 5.x or Vx routes, the idea is the same for things like pyramids. Note that the training log is just that: essentially blank pages. The manual (first link) is the actual training text.